# Flash AS3 List Component Labels Cropping?

Tags: actionscript-3, list, text, crop

For some reason, when I add a selectable list the labels in each cell keep getting cropped when the row height is increased. I believe this may happen because the original row height is 20, so the list automatically crops anything that goes outside of a box with row height of 20; so, my question would be: is there anyway to change this functionality?

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like: 
http://s7.postimg.org/6wqxfb1qz/Screen_Shot_2013_10_10_at_8_31_49_PM.png

Here is my code:

```
        list = new List();
        list.rowHeight = 50;
        list.setRendererStyle("contentPadding", 5);
        var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        myTextFormat.size = 20;
        myTextFormat.font = "Microsoft Sans Serif";
        list.setRendererStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat); 
        list.width = 118;
        list.height = stage.stageHeight - 60;
        list.focusEnabled = false;
        list.setStyle("contentPadding", 5);
        addCategories();
        list.move(0, 50);
        addChild(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the variableRowHeight property to make the height of List control rows variable based on their content

Here is the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d90.html#WS19f279b149e7481c32a1a3e512c12af2ad0-7ffc) explaining this,

you should add `list.variableRowHeight="true"`

Comment: adding that does not gives me a compiler error saying that "variableRowHeight" was not found. I believe this works for flex but not for as3. Is there anything else?